# Formik form not updating fields upon edit

Tags: reactjs, formik

I've been trying to rewrite my beginner form in React to use Formik.
I've gotten to the state that the form is being rendered, however, for some reason, I can't update the fields. It's clear that I made a mistake somewhere that prevents Formik from updating the state. What am I missing?

An example form component:

```
export const TextBox: React.SFC<FieldProps<any> & CustomFormElementProps> = ({
    field, // { name, value, onChange, onBlur }
    form: { touched, errors }, 
    loading,
    ...props
}) => (
        <div className="row form-group" key={field.name}>
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label">
                <ReactPlaceholder showLoadingAnimation ready={!loading} type="text" rows={1} className="control-label">
                    {props.label}
                </ReactPlaceholder>
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
                <ReactPlaceholder showLoadingAnimation ready={!loading} type="text" rows={1} className="form-control">
                    <input type="text"
                        disabled={props.disabled}
                        className="form-control"
                        id={field.name}
                        onChange={field.onChange}
                        onBlur={field.onBlur} {...props} />
                    {touched[field.name] && errors[field.name] && <span className="text-danger">{errors[field.name]}</span>}
                </ReactPlaceholder>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

The form is initialized in another component (which acts as a page template for the website);

```
renderFormElements() {
        var formFields = this.props.detailsElements.map((item) => {
            switch (item.type) {
                case FormElementType.TextLine:
                    return <TextLine
                        name={item.name}
                        label={item.label}
                        disabled={!this.state.editMode}
                        loading={item.loading}
                        value={item.defaultValue}
                        key={'TextBox_' + item.name}
                    />
                case FormElementType.TextBox:
                    return <Field
                        type="text"
                        name={item.name}
                        label={item.label}
                        component={InputElements.TextBox}
                        disabled={!this.state.editMode}
                        loading={item.loading}
                        value={item.defaultValue}
                        key={'TextBox_' + item.name}
                    />
                case FormElementType.DropDown:
                    return <Field
                        name={item.name}
                        label={item.label}
                        component={InputElements.DropDown}
                        disabled={!this.state.editMode}
                        loading={item.loading}
                        value={item.defaultValue}
                        options={item.options}
                        key={'DropDown_' + item.name}
                    />
                case FormElementType.RadioGroup:
                    return <Field
                        type="radio"
                        name={item.name}
                        label={item.label}
                        component={InputElements.RadioGroup}
                        disabled={!this.state.editMode}
                        loading={item.loading}
                        value={item.defaultValue}
                        options={item.options}
                        key={'RadioGroup' + item.name}
                    />
                }
        });

        var initialValues:{ [k: string]: any } = {};
        this.props.detailsElements.map((item) => {
            initialValues[item.name] = item.defaultValue;
        })
        console.log(initialValues);

        var formSection =
            (<Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
                    actions.setSubmitting(false)
                }, 1000)
            }}>
                <Form key="mainForm">
                    {formFields}
                </Form>
            </Formik>)

        return formSection;
```

I was assuming that the onChange event handler was taken care of by Formik, and that, if I didn't want to do special stuff, I did not need to provide anything to this. 
What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

your formFields function gets all of Formik props goodies. 
it contains `handleChange` - use this handler as your on change.

Also, make sure the field "id" is the same as the values key.

```
const {
  values,
  touched,
  errors,
  dirty,
  isSubmitting,
  handleChange,
  handleBlur,
  handleSubmit,
} = this.props;
<FormControl
      id="username"
      required
      placeholder="Enter Username"
      value={values.username}
      error={touched.username && errors.username}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
    />
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the formFields function? I'm passing the onChange already right, so what exactly is different?

Comment: no idea what is field.onChange, but you should use formik handleChange as explained

Comment: onChange is a property of Formiks FieldProps interface, I don't set it, it just gets passed. If I try handleChange then it complains it is not known in the FieldProps interface

Comment: have you matched the id of the Field with the values key ?

Comment: Yes, they're the same. Using the React inspector in Chrome I can see an 'Unknown component' with attribute={value: updatedvalue} but the value seems not to be pushed to the value of the actual input component; https://gyazo.com/89002bd53689822b8ec2f460c3182238

Comment: initialValues function returns empty object ? I think this is wrong. should return object with data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176247/discussion-between-mortana-and-idan-hen).

Comment: Next to this, the Reinitialize prop was missing, causing it not to update thé form when the initial values were updated (async API call)

Answer (score 3):

try putting the name attribute in the input element
name is what you got from field.name